# Write a general function in R that returns the line number of a specific vector

Tags: r

I built some data frame which is based on samples:

```
library(DescTools)

N <- 5
C <- 4

y <- CombSet(0:(C - 1), N, repl = TRUE, ord = FALSE)
data_y <- data.frame(y)

data_y_sort <- data_y[rev(order(rowSums(data_y), decreasing = T)), ]

x <- matrix(, nrow = choose(N + C - 1, C - 1), ncol = C)

for (i in 1:choose(N + C - 1, C - 1)) {
  for (j in 0:(C - 1)) {
    x[i, (j + 1)] <- sum(data_y_sort[i, ] == j)
  }
}

data <- data.frame(x)
```

I am now trying to write a general function that returns the row or "line" number where the row of my data is identical to some vector `a`. For example, for my example data the function should return 3 when the vector `c(3,2,0,0)` is passed as argument as it appears in the 3rd line in x.

That is, I need to compare each element in the rows of x with the argument in the function, and it will return me the appropriate line.

What I tried is:

```
new.function1 <- function(a) {
    result <- which(data[,i]==a[i])
    print(result)
}
```

I also tried

```
new.function2 <- function(a) {
    result <- which(for(i in 1:C){identical(data[,i],a[i])})
    print(result)
}
```

Unfortunately, none of them is working.

Comment: `which(x == 4, arr.ind = T)` will return the row and column index containing the value of 4. Do you want something like that? You can index the rows like this: `x[which(x == 4, arr.ind = T)[,1],]`. The indexing you have in the first function is not working because you haven't defined  `i`. I don't think you want a for loop inside `which` in the second one either :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```r
new.function <- function(x, a) {
  which(rowSums(as.matrix(x) == matrix(a, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = ncol(x), byrow = TRUE)) == ncol(x))
}

a <- c(3, 2, 0, 0)

new.function(data, a)
#> [1] 3
```

**DATA**

```r
data <- structure(list(X1 = c(
  5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
  3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
  2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), X2 = c(
  0L,
  1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L,
  2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L,
  0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), X3 = c(
  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L,
  0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L,
  0L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L,
  0L
), X4 = c(
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L,
  1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
  1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -56L
))
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much